# ARGScene-How can we setup ARGScene in swiftui using ARGear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The provided working in UIKit want to use in Swiftui.

private func setupScene() {
arScene = ARGScene(viewContainer: view)

```
    arScene.sceneRenderUpdateAtTimeHandler = { [weak self] renderer, time in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.refreshARFrame()
    }

    arScene.sceneRenderDidRenderSceneHandler = { [weak self] renderer, scene, time in
        guard let _ = self else { return }
    }

    cameraPreviewCALayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect//.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewCALayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: arScene.sceneView.frame.size.height, height: arScene.sceneView.frame.size.width)
    cameraPreviewCALayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewCALayer, at: 0)
}
```

Creating video recording application on swiftUI using ARGear beauty, filters and effects.
Please guid me if anyone know.